# How to fix cluster health yellow with Elastic Search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have setup on server, with MongoDb and ElasticSearch. Using https://github.com/richardwilly98/elasticsearch-river-mongodb I have connected ElasticSearch and MongoDb together.

I create a new index using:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/_river/mongodb/_meta' -d '{ 
        "type": "mongodb", 
        "mongodb": { 
        "db": "my_database", 
        "collection": "my_collection"
    }, 
        "index": {
        "name": "mainindex", 
        "type": "string",
        "bulk": {
            "concurrent_requests": 1
        }
    }
}'
```

Once the command is executed and I go to http://x.x.x.x:9200/_plugin/head/ I see the message: cluster health: yellow (1, 6).

[image: cluster health: yellow (1, 6)]

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

A cluster is being configured by having the same cluster name inside the elastic search config

The default elasticsearch.yml you are probably using has these settings in the Beginning like this:

```
################################### Cluster ###################################

# Cluster name identifies your cluster for auto-discovery. If you're running
# multiple clusters on the same network, make sure you're using unique names.
#
# cluster.name: elasticsearch


#################################### Node #####################################

# Node names are generated dynamically on startup, so you're relieved
# from configuring them manually. You can tie this node to a specific name:
#
# node.name: "Franz Kafka"
```

here you would need to configure a unique

`cluster.name: "MainCluster"`

and for each machine and/or instance a different unique

`node.name: "LocalMachine1"`

you now need to copy this `elasticsearch.yml` to another machine (in the same Network), or to the same place as e.g.`elasticsearch_2.yml` edit it for:

`node.name: "LocalMachine2"`

and your cluster is ready to go

if not configured elastiscsearch will use a random Marvel Character (of 3000 according the the documentation), so not to change the `node.name` should be ok also

For having two nodes running on the same machine,
you must make a configuration e.g. `elasticsearch_2.yml` copy, with above changes.
Also you must have copies of the data and log path
e.g. (homebrew specific paths:)

```
cp -r /usr/local/var/elasticsearch /usr/local/var/elasticsearch_2
cp -r /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch_2
```

might look like

```
#################################### Paths ####################################

# Path to directory containing configuration (this file and logging.yml):
#
# path.conf: /path/to/conf

# Path to directory where to store index data allocated for this node.
#
path.data: /usr/local/var/elasticsearch_2/
#
# Can optionally include more than one location, causing data to be striped across
# the locations (a la RAID 0) on a file level, favouring locations with most free
# space on creation. For example:
#
# path.data: /path/to/data1,/path/to/data2

# Path to temporary files:
#
# path.work: /path/to/work

# Path to log files:
#
path.logs: /usr/local/var/log/elasticsearch_2/
```

make sure you do not have running elasicsearch on localhost loopback device

127.0.0.1

just comment it out in case it is not (homebrew does patch ist this way)

```
############################## Network And HTTP ###############################

# Elasticsearch, by default, binds itself to the 0.0.0.0 address, and listens
# on port [9200-9300] for HTTP traffic and on port [9300-9400] for node-to-node
# communication. (the range means that if the port is busy, it will automatically
# try the next port).

# Set the bind address specifically (IPv4 or IPv6):
#
# network.bind_host: 192.168.0.1

# Set the address other nodes will use to communicate with this node. If not
# set, it is automatically derived. It must point to an actual IP address.
#
# network.publish_host: 192.168.0.1

# Set both 'bind_host' and 'publish_host':
#
# network.host: 127.0.0.1
```

now you can start elastic search like this:

```
bin/elasticsearch -D es.config=/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.0.0.RC1/config/elasticsearch.yml
```

for the first node and master (because started first)

and then

```
bin/elasticsearch -D es.config=/usr/local/Cellar/elasticsearch/1.0.0.RC1/config/elasticsearch_2.yml
```

Now you should have got 2 Nodes running

Comment: thanks for the feedback, I've tried to follow your process but I am running still into troubles. One problem is: when I restart the service the index I have created is gone, I need to reindex. Issue number two is not all documents get indexed... on time it is only 1000 of the 5500 the other time it is 5000 of the 5500. Can you set this things up for me, maybe trough a remote session so I can see where I did things wrong. Obvious you'll be rewarded.

Comment: FYI: I am running two nodes on one machine.

Answer (score 12):

Looks like you don't have a node for replica shards to go to. You can lower your replica count to 0 or add a second node to your cluster so that primary and replica shards can be safely placed on different nodes.

The default configuration in elasticsearch.yml is probably this:

```
index.number_of_shards: 5  
index.number_of_replicas: 1
```

The idea being that if your node crashes, another node in your cluster will have a copy of the shard. Since you only have one node, the cluster has no idea where to put the replicas and thus is in a yellow state.

Comment: how do we add a node to the cluster  ?

Comment: you can launch another jvm process pointing to a different config file, so imagine you have the es code installed in /opt/elasticsearch, you can have config/, data/, /logs, dirs in /opt/es-1, /opt/es-2. You can start es from the command line pointing to any number of configs using -Des.config=<..file..> creating a new node

Comment: Do i just need to point the cluster name for the second node so it will join it ? if so how can I do so ?

Comment: What is the syntax for pointing the config file for the node ?

Comment: elasticsearch -Des.config=PATH_TO_YOUR_CONFIG_FILE

Answer (score 4):

I am posting an answer since I tumbled upon this question while looking for solution of similar issue.

I have a dev environment where I need only 1 Elasticsearch node so there is no need for replicas for all my indices.

To solve **cluster health: yellow** issue, I just made `index.number_of_replicas: 1`

```
PUT /_settings
{
  "index" : {
        "number_of_replicas" : 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that the concept of `only 1 replica` does indeed equate to `"number_of_replicas" : 0` since a replica is a copy of the original.